# Making a GitHub repository editable by anyone

Tags: git, github

How would I make a repository on GitHub editable by anyone, without needing to invite collaborators?

Furthermore how would I create a GitHub account using Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not recommended, there are various auto-merge bots that can merge pull requests automatically under certain conditions. If set up liberally, this would effectively allow anybody to modify the repository.

One example: [probot-auto-merge](https://github.com/apps/probot-auto-merge)

Another [merge-me-action](https://github.com/ridedott/merge-me-action)

Answer (score -1):

If everyone could come in and edit, the project would be a mess and the cost of maintenance would be high

Comment: I know how would I make it possible though?